# ionic build for android

Tags: android, angular, ionic4

when i ran this command

> ionic cordova run android --livereload --consolelogs --emulator

i found this error

> [ng] Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>   [ng]   Data path ".builders['cordova-build']" should have required property 'class'.[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).       The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.

my package.json

```
{
    "name": "elmenu",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.17",
        "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
        "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
        "@angular/common": "~7.1.4",
        "@angular/core": "~7.1.4",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.1.4",
        "@angular/http": "~7.1.4",
        "@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.4",
        "@angular/router": "~7.1.4",
        "@capacitor/cli": "^1.2.1",
        "@capacitor/core": "^1.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.12.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.12.0",
        "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.14.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^4.20.0",
        "@ionic-native/http": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/native-page-transitions": "^5.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.21",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
        "@ionic-native/uid": "^5.14.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": "^0.6.5",
        "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
        "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
        "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.5.1",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-uid": "^1.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "ionic-angular": "^3.9.5",
        "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^1.0.5",
        "ngx-rating": "0.0.9",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "8.1.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.17",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.17",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.3.17",
        "@angular/cli": "^7.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.13",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.4",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "^4.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.12.0",
        "typescript": "~3.1.6"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
                "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-dreamover-uid": {},
            "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
            }
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: any hint please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1"

```
npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit@1.5.1 --save-dev
```

More info [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/issues/166).

Comment: not working 
> [ng] Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
[ng] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined